# Search for values between textboxes and filters it to datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Can anyone help me? I need a search button to look for the values(price) between two textboxes(txtMin and txtMax) and loads it to the DataGridview.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=root; database=realestate"
    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource
    Dim dv As New DataView(dbDataSet)

    Try
        con.Open()
        Dim q1 As String
        q1 = "Select * from realestate.transactions"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(q1, con)
        SDA.SelectCommand = cmd
        SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
        bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
        frmHome.DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
        SDA.Update(dbDataSet)
        dv.RowFilter = String.Format("[propertyid] like '%{0}%' AND [type] like '%{1}%' **AND Convert(price,'System.String') Like '%{2}%'** AND Convert(nobed,'System.String') Like '%{3}%' AND Convert(nobath,'System.String') Like '%{4}%' AND Convert(footages,'System.String') Like '%{5}%' AND [location] like '%{6}%' AND [status] like '%{7}%'", txtProperty.Text, cmbType.Text, **txtMin.Text**, cmbBed.Text, cmbBath.Text, txtFootages.Text, txtLocation.Text, cmbStatus.Text)
        frmHome.DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
        If frmHome.DataGridView1.RowCount > 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Search Successful")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No records found")
        End If
        con.Close()
        txtProperty.Text = ""
        cmbType.Text = ""
        txtFootages.Text = ""
        txtMax.Text = ""
        txtMin.Text = ""
        cmbBath.Text = ""
        cmbBed.Text = ""
        cmbStatus.Text = ""
        Me.Hide()
        frmHome.DataGridView1.Columns(0).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

On my code, it will only search the values(price) what I have entered in the txtMin.text. How will I code this one to search for values between txtMin.text and txtMax.text. Please see attached image for your references

[Search Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orAKc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a decimal numerical field value for the price in your database.
Then you could update your filter to search a value between the values you entered in txtMin and txtMax.

Assuming that your filter is getting compiled, you can update it as following:

```
dv.RowFilter = 
String.Format("
[propertyid] like '%{0}%' AND 
[type] like '%{1}%' **AND 
price >{2} AND price<{3} AND 
Convert(nobed,'System.String') Like '%{4}%' AND 
Convert(nobath,'System.String') Like '%{5}%' AND 
Convert(footages,'System.String') Like '%{6}%' AND 
[location] like '%{7}%' AND 
[status] like '%{8}%'", 
txtProperty.Text, cmbType.Text, Single.Parse(txtMin.Text),     Single.Parse(txtMax.Text), cmbBed.Text, cmbBath.Text, txtFootages.Text,     txtLocation.Text, cmbStatus.Text)
```

For the footage, it is the same approach:
You will need to add two textboxes for footages range: txtFootageMin and txtFootageMax:

```
dv.RowFilter = 
String.Format("
[propertyid] like '%{0}%' AND 
[type] like '%{1}%' **AND 
price >{2} AND price<{3} AND 
Convert(nobed,'System.String') Like '%{4}%' AND 
Convert(nobath,'System.String') Like '%{5}%' AND 
footages >{6} AND footages<{7} AND 
[location] like '%{8}%' AND 
[status] like '%{9}%'", 
txtProperty.Text, cmbType.Text, Single.Parse(txtMin.Text),     Single.Parse(txtMax.Text), cmbBed.Text, cmbBath.Text,    Single.Parse(txtFootageMin.Text), Single.Parse(txtFootageMax.Text),       txtLocation.Text, cmbStatus.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for the footage along with price:

```
Dim result As Single
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMin.Text.Trim()) Then
        result = Single.MinValue
    Else
        result = Single.Parse(txtMin.Text)
    End If
    Dim result2 As Single
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMax.Text.Trim()) Then
        result2 = Single.MaxValue
    Else
        result2 = Single.Parse(txtMax.Text)
    End If
    Dim result3 As Single
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFootMin.Text.Trim()) Then
        result3 = Single.MaxValue
    Else
        result3 = Single.Parse(txtFootMin.Text)
    End If
    Dim result4 As Single
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFootMax.Text.Trim()) Then
        result4 = Single.MaxValue
    Else
        result4 = Single.Parse(txtFootMax.Text)
    End If
dv.RowFilter = String.Format("[propertyid] like '%{0}%' AND [type] like '%{1}%' AND price >={2} AND price<={3} AND Convert(nobed,'System.String') Like '%{4}%' AND Convert(nobath,'System.String') Like '%{5}%' AND footages >={6} AND footages<={7} AND [location] like '%{8}%' AND [status] like '%{9}%'", txtProperty.Text, cmbType.Text, result, result2, cmbBed.Text, cmbBath.Text, result3, result4, txtLocation.Text, cmbStatus.Text)
```